# Can't add a hashtag # into my share twitter button

Tags: html, button, twitter, share, hashtag

I have a twitter share button on my page. I use this code because I want a custom icon. My problem is I can't seem to add a hashtag into the custom text. Where it says 'custom text' is where I input my tweet.

```
  <a class="icon-twitter" rel="nofollow"
       href="http://twitter.com/"
       onclick="popUp=window.open(
           'http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text= custom text',
           'popupwindow',
           'scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=400');
     popUp.focus();
     return false">
     <i class="visuallyhidden"><img class="social-media" src="images/twitter.png"/></i>
  </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode the `#`. This is because the `#` will otherwise be treated as the hash part of the url, and not a part of the `text` querystring, just like a `&` would be interpreted as a separator between two querystring parameters, rather than a part of the value, unless you encode it to `%26`. If the "custom text" can be anything, use `encodeURIComponent`:

```
'http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent('#custom #text')
```

If the value will always be hard coded, replacing the `#` with `%23` would do:

```
'http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=%23custom %23text'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better for sharing hashtags:
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=Tag1,Tag2

[Source](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent)